# JQuery Scroll to Offset from top of browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scroll script, which scrolls round the page fine, works exactly how i want it too.

```
$(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
        && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var $target = $(this.hash);
            $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if ($target.length) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

However, i need it to ignore the top say 200px as i have a fixed header at the top of the page that the content scrolls behind.

Meaning that when i scroll to top it scrolls the content to behind the fixed header so i cannot see it, so i need it to scroll to just below the header.. so to treat the bottom of the header as the top of the browser i suppose....

Can this be done as it would be very handy?

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Thank you for asking this question been struggling all night trying to understand how to accomplish this for the exact same reason!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - 200;
```

Or grab the height of the header element for the extra offset.

```
var targetOffset = $target.offset().top - $("element").outerHeight(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this if condition on ur code to do that

```
//check if the absolute position is below header
if ($('#IdOfTheScrollElement').position().top >= 200 ){
//scroll
}
else {
//do nothing
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I'm not sure if they work though as i couldn't figure out where to put them in the code to have an effect, in mist cases i just broke the scroll :(

Answer (score 1):

The Code is fine, you just need to remove the height of your fixed header here, for example if it's 200px. it will work perfectly.

```
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: (targetOffset().top)-200}, 1000);
```

You can also check this when a button is clicked

```
$(function() {

$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

    // Check height of the header and padding
    var header_height = $('.header').outerHeight();
```

Remove it from your offset

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: (targetOffset().top) - header_height }, 1000);
```